# Adding punctuations inside dictionary values?

Tags: python

I have a dictionary as output that has some numerics:

```
example_dict = dict{'X': OrderedDict, 'Y': OrderedDict}

print(example_dict)

example_dict = {'X': OrderedDict(['Value1', '100000', 
                                  'Value2', '10000', 
                                  'Value3', '1000'])
                'Y': OrderedDict(['Value4', '2000', 
                                  'Value5', '20000', 
                                  'Value6', '200000'])}
```

And I would like Python to print this output with commas automatically assigned to the proper places so that the new output becomes:

```
example_dict = {'X': OrderedDict(['Value1', '100,000', 
                                  'Value2', '10,000', 
                                  'Value3', '1000'])
                'Y': OrderedDict(['Value4', '2000', 
                                  'Value5', '20,000', 
                                  'Value6', '200,000'])}
```

These values can be random throughout the dictionary and not in the fashion that I described above. In some places hundred thousands are altogether missing while some have only numerals in thousands. That is, I need to define the function such that any value in the dictionary that has 5 digits inserts a ',' between the forth and the third digit and so on.

Comment: It is not `tuple`, infact not a valid python data structure though resemble more like `dict`

Comment: This is not a tuple, this looks like something between a dictionary and a set, but not valid Python.

Comment: Sorry. I'm new to Python and some of its data structures are similar. But I've added corrections.

Comment: Corrections? That is still incorrect syntax.

Comment: You are looking for thousand separator. but the syntax is wrong.

Comment: Do you just want to add commas to a number? If you can do that, doing it to everything in a dictionary should be easy.

Comment: And for the syntax: do you just want `{'X': ['100000','10000',1000], ...}`

Comment: Yes but for a random number? I can iterate over that dictionary but how to tell Python to look for a specific digit and insert a comma at the right place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure of kind of `OrderedDict` you have, but I've made an attempt as per my understanding.

You can add commas with custom function and replace innerdict values as needed.

Hopefully this helps.

**Sample Code**

```
from collections import OrderedDict    

#Build your dict (sort of)
x = ['Value1', '100000', 'Value2', '10000', 'Value3', '1000']
y = ['Value4', '2000', 'Value5', '20000', 'Value6', '200000']

z = {'X': OrderedDict([x[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(x),2)]),  
     'Y': OrderedDict([y[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(y),2)]),
     }

#function to set commas, you can expand as needed
def getNum(a):
    if len(a)   == 5: return a[0:2] + ',' + a[2:]
    elif len(a) == 6: return a[0:3] + ',' + a[3:]
    else: return a


#Add commas to inner dict
for k,innerdict in z.iteritems():
    for k2,v2 in innerdict.iteritems():
        innerdict[k2] = getNum(v2)
```

**Result**

```
#`z` before changes  
    >>> 
    {'Y': OrderedDict([('Value4', '2000'), ('Value5', '20000'), ('Value6',   '200000')]),  
    'X': OrderedDict([('Value1', '100000'), ('Value2', '10000'),   ('Value3', '1000')])}  

#`z` after changes  
    {'Y': OrderedDict([('Value4', '2000'), ('Value5', '20,000'), ('Value6', '200,000')]),
     'X': OrderedDict([('Value1', '100,000'),  
 ('Value2', '10,000'), ('Value3', '1000')])}  
    >>>
```

Comment: Will be more careful while reproducing the code next time. I actually had a dictionary as output and not as tuple (my bad) that made things confusing for everyone here. Apologies for that. But your code worked! Finally some readable numbers!